# Polymer bounded property not updating (sometimes)

Tags: javascript, binding, polymer

This problem is with 1.0

I have the following html in a polymer element

```
  <iron-selector attr-for-selected="step-number" selected="{{stepNumber}}">
    <section step-number="1">
      <page-1 id="page1"></page-1>
    </section>
    <section step-number="2">
      <page-2 id="page2"></page-2>
    </section>
    <section step-number="3">
      <page-3 id="page3"></page-3>
    </section>`
```

page 1 fires an event - event1, page-2 fires event2. Here's my javascript for the polymer element

```
function () {
  Polymer({
    is: 'name',
    ready: function() {
      this.stepNumber = 1;
      var firstStep = this.$.page1;
      var secondStep = this.$.page2;
      var thirdStep = this.$.page3;
      var that = this;
      firstStep.addEventListener('event1', function(e) {
        that.stepNumber = 2;                       // WORKING
      });
      secondStep.addEventListener('event2', function(e) {
        that.stepNumber = 3;                      // NOT WORKING
      });
    }
  });
```

Here's the interesting part:
Both events get fired, the value for `stepNumber` gets updated inside `event1` handler but not inside `event2` handler. I also debugged this and inside the `event2` handler the value of `stepNumber` DOES get updated (page-3 element gets the tag "iron-selected") but it doesn't persist. After a bunch of polymer code executes the value is back to 2.

Looks like a bug in polymer?

Some info from the debugger -

polymer code that's executing after the event method is basically the code that executes the event handler, followed by a "gesture recognition" code (which i guess is the on-click), where the tag iron-selector is added to page-2 section

```
var recognizers = Gestures.recognizers;

for (var i = 0, r; i < recognizers.length; i++) 
{ 
   r = recognizers[i]; 
   if (gs[r.name] && !handled[r.name]) {
     handled[r.name] = true; // in here for r.name = "tap"
   r[type](ev); // type = click. ev = MouseEvent. ev.target = iron-selector
} 
}
```

Digging deeper - 
this creates an event handler

```
_createEventHandler: function(node, eventName, methodName) {
var host = this;
return function(e) {
if (host[methodName]) {
hostmethodName;
} else {
host._warn(host._logf("_createEventHandler", "listener method " + methodName + " not defined"));
}
};
```

host is iron-selector. methodName is _activateHandler where _itemActivate is called for section of page-2

```
_activateHandler: function(e) {
      // TODO: remove this when https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/1639 is fixed so we
      // can just remove the old event listener.
      if (e.type !== this.activateEvent) {
        return;
      }
      var t = e.target;
      var items = this.items;
      while (t && t != this) {
        var i = items.indexOf(t);
        if (i >= 0) {
          var value = this._indexToValue(i);
          this._itemActivate(value, t);
          return;
        }
        t = t.parentNode;
      }
    },
_itemActivate: function(value, item) {
      if (!this.fire('iron-activate',
          {selected: value, item: item}, {cancelable: true}).defaultPrevented) {
        this.select(value);
      }
```

_itemActivate is where the value of stepNumber changes to 2

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the events are and how they're fired? You may need to `debounce` them, or use `async` to make the `stepNumber` assignment wait for Polymer to finish what it's doing first.

Comment: Zikes,  this polymer element is like a workflow, every page is like a workflow step. The events are fired when the workflow step completes.

 For example, page-1 is a searching page. When the user clicks on search button, event1 is fired. Page-2 is a search result listing page. When one of the items in the list is clicked event2 is fired.

Could you elaborate a little on async. ?

Comment: Just looked at the polymer code that's executing after the event method executes.

It's basically the code that executes the event handler, followed by a "gesture recognition" code, where the value of "stepNumber" magically rolls back to 2

It's something like this - 

`var recognizers = Gestures.recognizers;
for (var i = 0, r; i < recognizers.length; i++) {
r = recognizers[i];
if (gs[r.name] && !handled[r.name]) {
handled[r.name] = true;
r[type](ev);
}
}`

Comment: added some more info. don't know if its useful

Comment: raised a bug https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-selector/issues/35

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear the `activateEvent` property (`activate-event` attribute) of the `iron-selector`, like this:

`<iron-selector attr-for-selected="step-number" selected="{{stepNumber}}" activate-event="">`

Comment: Hi Scott, Thanks for the "workaround", it works. Although do you agree that this is a bug and is it in your radar for future releases ? I also filed a bug on iron-selector yesterday but got no replies. Please ack. github.com/PolymerElements/iron-selector/issues/35

Comment: The above is not a workaround IMO, it's simply the correct usage. By the same token, this is not a bug IMO, `activateEvent` is a feature of iron-selector that allows elements to be self-selecting. If you want to manage the selection of items yourself, you can clear this value as shown.

Comment: Scott, In that case, couple of advices from a fellow googler: 1. Add documentation for the same. 2. it should be disabled by default. As a user this wasn't expected. I don't know how or when the selector decides to select itself. An explanation into that would be amazing.

Comment: This is documented in `iron-selector`. I don't disagree that the documentation needs improving, and we are working on it, but it's a massive corpus of material and we are a small team. Lastly, the default is `tap` because this is by far the common case.

Comment: Thanks, then my final comment will be a summary of the problem I faced, maybe there is something that can be done to alleviate this problem later.

When page 2 was selected and being displayed, i clicked on something in the page that triggered an event which ultimately selected page 3. Unfortunately the activateEvent handler also fired up (on-tap) and selected page 2 back...

Comment: Fwiw, in `iron-pages` I recently modified it to set no default `activateEvent` to avoid the exact problem you describe above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Polymer({
  is: 'name',
  ready: function() {
    this.stepNumber = 1;
    var firstStep = this.$.page1;
    var secondStep = this.$.page2;
    var thirdStep = this.$.page3;
    var that = this;
    firstStep.addEventListener('event1', function(e) {
      that.async(function(){
        that.stepNumber = 2;
      },0);
    });
    secondStep.addEventListener('event2', function(e) {
      that.async(function(){
        that.stepNumber = 3;
      },0);
    });
  }
});
```